# SQL Server Select Records within a Configured Date and Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a configuration table and stored a configured value as RetIntervel as 10,8.30 PM. I need to retrieve all the records which dates are exceeded 10 days and after 8.30 PM (after 10 days and 8.30 PM). I have tried below condition and it is not getting proper result.

```
Select * From Table 
Where 
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,10,CreatedDate),'8:30 PM') >GETDATE()
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF(day,10,CreatedDate)` Do you understand that the 2nd parameter is a date - how is the value of "10" interpreted as a date? When your complex nested express does not do what you expect, you start debugging it by examining each expression and its result from the inside out.

Answer (score 0):

Why use it like below

```
Select * From Table 
Where 
    CreatedDate >DATEADD(n, 1230,DATEADD(d,10,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
```